# Code runner: code language not supported or defined

Tags: kotlin, vscode-code-runner

I just finished to setup Kotlin in Vscode, and download Coderunner to run test code such as "Hello world!". However, no matter how I tried, Code runner gave me this error: ***Code language not supported or defined.***

I did almost everything what I can find about this error, however, it kept give me the same result. How can I fix this?

Platform: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am facing the same.